# R: Assigning the mean of a variable using the formula $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^NX_i$

Tags: r, mean

I need to assign the mean of X to a different variable called X_bar. How would I do this using the formula $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^NX_i$ and only the functions length() and sum()?

Comment: `x_bar <- sum(x)/length(x)` but be careful with missing values,see `help("sum")`.

Comment: With `NA`'s, use `sum(x,na.rm=TRUE)/sum(!is.na(x))`.